# What is dvilualatex made for? Strange output

Tags: luatex, dvips, dvi-mode

I might be asking something stupid, but why does pushing `mwe.tex` containing

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}
```

through `dvilualatex mwe && dvips mwe` lead to the output

[image: output]

both in `mwe.dvi` and `mwe.ps` ?

I thought that `dvilualatex` is there for generating a DVI file via `luatex` instead of `latex`, isn't it?

By the way, `dvips` prints a strange font-not-found error message to the console although the font file exists:

```
$ dvips mwe && ls -la /usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf
This is dvips(k) 2021.1 (TeX Live 2022/dev)  Copyright 2021 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' LuaTeX output 2022.03.07:1640' -> mwe.ps
dvips: Font [/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf] not found; using cmr10
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600/cmr10.pk>
dvips: Checksum mismatch in font [/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf]
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/base/tex.pro>
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.pro>
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/base/special.pro>. [1] 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 111536  7. Okt 2009  /usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf
```

We use

```
$ dvilualatex --version
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.14.0 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)
$ dvips --version
This is dvips(k) 2021.1 (TeX Live 2022/dev)  Copyright 2021 Radical Eye Software
kpathsea version 6.3.4/dev
```

Comment: Oh I'm surprised you got anything at all, I think some recent versions of xdvipdfmx can do better but in general dviluatex makes a dvi file referencing opentype fonts in a form that most dvi drivers that pre-exist opentype can not use.

Comment: if you want classic dvi and have  access to lua, you can do that but configure luatex to use 7 or 8bit tfm fonts OT1 or T1 encoding in latex, not TU encoded opentype or truetype fonts.

Comment: note dvips is ignoring the font you specified and going back to its roots with cmr10: `using cmr10 \`</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600/cmr10.pk>` so the fact that the letters looked more or less the same letters as the input was by luck not design.

Comment: dvisvg and dvipdfmx can make use of the dvi, dvips can't.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. What would be a minimal working example of using `dvilualatex` and `dvisvg`/ `dvipdfmx` to generate a meaningful DVI file and then a Postscript file? We can choose any font you like (though I prefer TeX Gyre). Is there any “walkthough” on this online?

Comment: you really want PostScript as the end result? why not use luatex then use ghostcript pdf2ps ? (TeX Gyre are exactly what I suggested not to use, they are Opentype Unicode fonts)

Comment: @GeekestGeek: For `dvipdfmx` you can use your input as is to produce PDF. For `dvisvgm` too, but you get SVG instead of PDF.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Surely we can go through lualatex and pdf2ps. I simply want to understand whether we can still generate a Postscript file more-or-less directly from the LaTeX source (under the assumption that we need lua because, e.g., we'd like to have a particular OTF font or because of nice encoding of mathematical characters via unicode-math or for some other reason).

Comment: as I say, you can if you could use the same fonts with classic dvi latex. Doing it with fonts that you could not use with latex is harder (or impossible, depending)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh. So if you say we could use the same fonts as with classic dvi latex, why does the standard (IMHO Computer Modern) font fail? Or, maybe, do I misunderstand the goal of `dvilualatex`, and it's *not* for generating Postscript files via the LaTeX → DVI → Postscript path?

Comment: because the dvi has the checksum and character positioning as specified by luatex for latin modern opentype, dvips can't read that so it uses cmr10.pk bitmaps  but it has no mapping to the type1 version of that and the encoding and metrics don't actually match the encoding and metrics used to write the data to the dvi file so anything that comes out is just accidental nonsense. Here it's simple ascii so almost looks plausible but....

Comment: The default font in lualatex hasn't been OT1 computer modern since about 2015 or so.  it is Unicode (TU)  Latin Modern (as seen in the dvips error messages that you quoted)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. So would saying `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{lmodern}` or `\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}` make `dvilualatex` produce a usable DVI file that `dvips` would be able to process? Or is it not how it is supposed to work?

Comment: dvilualatex isn't really usable with dvips. It would require a dvips update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to do some things it is more or less true that dviluatex if using OpenType fonts will write a dvi file that no dvi driver can use. (dvipdfmx has some support for this in recent releases, but that doesn't help if the aim is to get PostScript).

In the dvips output that you show, you see it failing on the Unicode OpenType Latin Modern, substituting its error fallback cmr10 pk bitmaps and hoping for the best.....

If you use a 7 or 8 bit classic Tex font, the resulting dvi file is usable eg

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Hello world

\directlua{tex.write('look Lua is here!')}

\end{document}
```

has a clean run in dvilualatex

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./cc059.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
 L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd))
(/home/davidc/texmf/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def) (./cc059.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd) [1] (./cc059.aux)
)
 406 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec
, 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:33,3:11,4:2,5:24,6:6,7:139,9:36
Output written on cc059.dvi (1 page, 296 bytes).
Transcript written on cc059.log.
```

and dvips is happy

```
$ dvips cc059
This is dvips(k) 2022.1 (TeX Live 2022)  Copyright 2022 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' LuaTeX output 2022.03.07:1636' -> cc059.ps
</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/dvips/base/tex.pro>
</home/davidc/texmf/dvips/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-ec.enc>
</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/dvips/base/texps.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/dvips/base/special.pro>. 
</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr10.pfb>[1]
```

and the resulting  PostScript uses scalable type 1 Latin Modern:

[image]

Comment: "no dvi driver" isn't quite right. dvilualatex + dvipdfmx works fine (at least in texlive2022), even if opentype fonts are used.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes I said that in comments under the question originally but (a) I'm not sure it really works in all cases and (b) if you want pdf you may as well use lualatex, the OP seemed to want dvi->PostScript.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer but I noted dvipdfmx in the answer now

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! That's right: for the purpose of this particular question, I'm interested in the most direct way from LaTeX to Postscript, which I presume to be the LaTeX → DVI → Postscript path. (Consider, e.g., the (I admit, seldom) case that you wish to have both PSTricks and Lua for some reason.)

Comment: @GeekestGeek  if you want pstricks and lua, simply try with lualatex. With a current texsystem it should work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'll try; thank you! But won't it generate a PDF file first (and, as we know, not all Postscript features also work in PDF)?

Comment: @GeekestGeek PSTricks in LuaLaTeX uses a (partial) PostScript interpreter written in Lua to interpret the PostScript commands and directly generate a PDF out of them.